# TypeError: __init__(): incompatible constructor arguments with face_recognition call

Tags: python, face-recognition, dlib, pybind11

I was trying to develop a face recognition attendance system, I coded 100% just like the tutorial, but I still got some errors, here's the code:

```
from face_recognition.api import face_distance
import face_recognition as fr
import os
import cv2
import face_recognition
import numpy as np
import time
from PIL import ImageFont

def getEncodedFaces():
    encoded = {}
    for dirPath, dNames, fNames in os.walk("./faces"):
        for f in fNames:
            if f.endswith(".jpg") or f.endswith(".png"):
                face = fr.load_image_file("faces/" + f)
                encoding = fr.face_encodings(face)[0]
                encoded[f.split(".")[0]] + encoding
    return encoded

def unknownImageEncoded(img):
    face = fr.load_image_file("faces/" + img)
    encoding = fr.face_encodings(face)[0]
    return encoding

def classifyFace(im):
    faces = getEncodedFaces()
    facesEncoded = list(faces.values())
    knownFaceNames = list(faces.keys())
    img = cv2.imread(im, 1)
    faceLocations = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)
    unknownFaceEncodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(img, faceLocations)
    faceNames = []
    for faceEncoding in unknownFaceEncodings:
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces()
        name = "Unknown"
        faceDistances = face_recognition.face_distance(facesEncoded, faceEncoding)
        bestMatchIndex = np.argmin(face_distance)
        if matches[bestMatchIndex]:
            name = knownFaceNames[bestMatchIndex]
        faceNames.append(name)
        for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(faceLocations, faceNames):
            cv2.rectangle(img, (left-20, top-20, right+20, bottom+20), (255, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)
            font = ImageFont.truetype("./NotoSansTC-Black.ttf")
            cv2.putText(img, name, (left-20, bottom+15), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 2)
    
    while True:
        cv2.imshow("Attendance System", img)
        if cv2.waitkey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            return faceNames

print(classifyFace("test.jpg"))
```

And here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 51, in <module>
    print(classifyFace("test.jpg"))
  File "main.py", line 31, in classifyFace
    unknownFaceEncodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(img, faceLocations)
  File "C:\Users\family\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 213, in face_encodings
    raw_landmarks = _raw_face_landmarks(face_image, known_face_locations, model)
  File "C:\Users\family\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 158, in _raw_face_landmarks
    face_locations = [_css_to_rect(face_location) for face_location in face_locations]
  File "C:\Users\family\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 158, in <listcomp>
    face_locations = [_css_to_rect(face_location) for face_location in face_locations]
  File "C:\Users\family\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 49, in _css_to_rect
    return dlib.rectangle(css[3], css[0], css[1], css[2])
TypeError: __init__(): incompatible constructor arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. _dlib_pybind11.rectangle(left: int, top: int, right: int, bottom: int)
    2. _dlib_pybind11.rectangle(rect: dlib::drectangle)
    3. _dlib_pybind11.rectangle(rect: _dlib_pybind11.rectangle)
    4. _dlib_pybind11.rectangle()

Invoked with: -0.035434916615486145, -0.12049627304077148, 0.08377307653427124, 0.062198664993047714
```

Here's the directory structure:

```
test.JPG
main.py
NotoSansTC-Black.otf
faces
|- 呂AA.jpg
|- 呂BB.jpg
```

Can someone tell me what does it mean and how to fix it? I have tried installing many different versions of dlib and face-recognition. I've also installed pybind11, but it is still giving me the same error. I'm in a hurry and I really need some help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you importing `face_recognition` 2 times? It is not proper way to import `face_recognition` 2 times.

`compare_faces()` takes 2 arguments, already encoded vector list and unknown encoded vector.

And now focusing on your main error, you have not used `face_locations` which means it wont locate your face from the image.

Your error is here:

```py
faceLocations = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)
```

Instead use this:

```py
faceLocations = face_recognition.face_locations(img)
```

full code:

```py
from face_recognition.api import face_distance
import face_recognition as fr
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
from PIL import ImageFont

def getEncodedFaces():
    encoded = {}
    for f in os.listdir(os.path.join('faces')):
        face = fr.load_image_file(os.path.join('faces',f))
        encoding = fr.face_encodings(face)
        if not len(encoding):
           continue
        encoding = encoding[0]
        encoded[f.split(".")[0]] = encoding
    return encoded

def unknownImageEncoded(img):
    face = fr.load_image_file("faces/" + img)
    encoding = fr.face_encodings(face)[0]
    return encoding

def classifyFace(im):
    faces = getEncodedFaces()
    facesEncoded = list(faces.values())
    knownFaceNames = list(faces.keys())
    img = cv2.imread(im, 1)
    faceLocations = fr.face_locations(img)
    unknownFaceEncodings = fr.face_encodings(img, faceLocations)
    faceNames = []
    for faceEncoding, faceloc in zip(unknownFaceEncodings, faceLocations):
        top, right, bottom, left = faceloc
        matches = fr.compare_faces(facesEncoded, faceEncoding)
        name = "Unknown"
        faceDistances = fr.face_distance(facesEncoded, faceEncoding)
        bestMatchIndex = np.argmin(faceDistances)
        if matches[bestMatchIndex]:
            name = knownFaceNames[bestMatchIndex]
            faceNames.append(name)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (left-20, top-20, right+20, bottom+20), (255, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)
            font = ImageFont.truetype("./NotoSansTC-Black.ttf")
            cv2.putText(img, name, (left-20, bottom+15), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 2)
    

    image = img[:, :, ::-1]
    cv2.imwrite("result.jpg", image)
    return faceNames

print(classifyFace("test.jpg"))
```

Comment: Thanks! It does fix the problem! But then I receive another problem which is at `if matches[bestMatchIndex]:`, I receive index out of range, can you help me on this? Thank you!

Comment: @SaxTed yes there are many small mistakes in your code. I will fix it wait

Comment: Thank you so muuuuuuuuuuuuuch!!!!!! I wrote just as what the tutorial wrote though.

Comment: can you check my updated code? Is it fixed now?

Comment: @SaxTed Oh you forgot to use the same variable `faceDistances`. Now check my code again

Comment: Yeah it fixes this one! But it says `ValueError: attempt to get argmin of an empty sequence`, seems like faceDistances is empty?

Comment: @SaxTed can you try printing the values of `facesEncoded` and `faceEncoding`?

Comment: facesEncoded is empty, and faceEncoding is a list full of floats. Btw can I have your contact ways? I think we've got too many comments here, it writes `please avoid extended discussions in comments`

Comment: seems like `getEncodedFaces()` is not returning anything in your case. Can you update the question showing the full directory structure? It may not have found the images for encoding

Comment: Oh the directory structure is really simple, main.py, test.jpg, faces/me.jpg and faces/dad.jpg

Comment: @SaxTed see my updated code, hope it helps

Comment: can you use `print(getEncodedFaces())` and see what the result is?

Comment: It returns {}, a blank dict

Comment: There might still be directory not matching problem. I have assumed that your main.py code is outside of `faces` folder. LIke this: main.py, faces. Inside faces, I assumed that you have .jpg files. Could you update your question about how your directory looks like? Please print `f` to see whether images exists or not

Comment: I just updated the question, also, it prints nothing even when I print f, seems like it really didn't read the file.

Comment: @SaxTed print this , `print(os.path.exists(os.path.join('faces')))` and `print(os.path.exists(os.path.join('faces', 'dad.jpg')))`. If both shows True then your directory exists. If False is printed then tey dont exists. I will again update the code with next method if they dont exists

Comment: Both returns true

Comment: @SaxTed are there only images inside faces folder? If there are only images inside faces folder then you can remove that `if` condition which checks whether it is `jpg` or `png`. See my updated code.

Comment: It is no longer giving errors! But it doesn't show any interface, just stuck there.

Comment: @SaxTed I have updated my code which will create a new file `result.jpg`. If you want to detect and recognize faces from live camera, this video might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sz25xxF_AVE

Answer (score 1):

This line: `for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(faceLocations, faceNames):` .

Make sure that `top, right, bottom, left` values are integer values and not float values. Just print them once to confirm. If they are float values convert them to int using `int()`. Like this:

```
for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(faceLocations, faceNames):
   cv2.rectangle(img, int(left)-20, int(top)-20, int(right)+20, int(bottom)+20), (255, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply! I just added the `int()` but it is still giving the same error.

Comment: Try printing the values of those and see if the values are int or float.